# Php muilti array echo

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php has below how i can echo in php.

i want to echo like this

```
Veg.Pizaa => 
          Extra = > Cheese, price 50
          Vegetables = > Avocado, price 25
```

The Array Is Below

```
array
  (
     'Veg.Pizaa' => 
      (
        array
          (
            'Extra' => 
             (
               array
                (
                 'name' => string '25g Cheese' (length=10),
                 'price' => string '50' (length=2),
                 'quanty' => int 13,
                 'Vegetables' =>
                ), 
               array
                (
                 'name' => string 'Avocado' (length=7),
                 'price' => string '25' (length=2),
                 'quanty' => int 13,
                 'Nuts' =>
                 ), 
               array
                (
                 'name' => string 'Almonds' (length=7),
                 'price' => string '30' (length=2),
                 'quanty' => int 21
                )
             )
          )
       )
    )
```

I've tried the following code

```
foreach($sub as $sub) {
  var_dump($sub);
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><h3 style='font-weight: bolder; color: Maroon; line-height: 10px;'>".$sub[0]['productname']
    ."</h3></td>";
  echo "<td><h3 style='font-weight: bolder; color: Maroon; line-height: 10px;'>".$sub[0]['qty']
    ."</h3></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: @vaahost: Where's the question? What do you get for output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = ...;

foreach( $array as $key => $val )
{
  echo $key . " =>\n";

  foreach( $val as $key2 => $val2 )
  {
    echo "\t" . $key2 . ' => ' . $val2['name'] . "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    echo $key.' ';
    if(is_array($val)
    {
        foreach($val as $name => $qty)
        {
            if($name=='name')
            {
                echo $qty;
            }
            if($name=='price')
            {
                echo $name.', '.$qty.'\n<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just do:

```
print_r($array)
```

That's what I'd use to debug an array.

Comment: See i have asked for an html output

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Maybe let us know what you're aiming to do with the information? Do you just want to show the array as nested lists maybe?